# Extract text from html string with beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I write the following code to extract price from webpage:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://www.teleborsa.it/azioni/intesa-sanpaolo-isp-it0000072618-SVQwMDAwMDcyNjE4"
html = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
prize = soup.select('.h-price')
print(prize)
```

output is:

```
<span class="h-price fc0" id="ctl00_phContents_ctlHeader_lblPrice">1,384</span>
```

i want to extract 1,384 value.

Comment: ```prize.string```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
document.getElementById("ctl00_phContents_ctlHeader_lblPrice").innerText
```

Or if you are having dynamic elements, you can iterate over each element and get innerText from it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.text` property to get the desired text.

For example:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://www.teleborsa.it/azioni/intesa-sanpaolo-isp-it0000072618-SVQwMDAwMDcyNjE4"
html = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
prize = soup.select_one('.h-price') # <- change to .select_one() to get only one element
print(prize.text)                   # <- use the .text property to get text of the tag
```

Prints:

```
1,384
```